# Laravel 6 query same table with different where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-query-builder

I have `campaign_report` table like this

```
Schema::create('campaign_report', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->date('report_date');
    $table->bigInteger('user_id');
    $table->bigInteger('campaignId');
    $table->double('cost',12,2);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I am trying to get all yesterday's campaign reports.

```
        $campaignReports = CampaignReport::where(['report_date' => "$yesterday", 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id])->orderBy('report_date', 'desc')->paginate(25);
```

Above query is returning all campaigns where report_date is equal to $yesterday.

Along with this query I also want to get the `cost` value of each campaign where `report_date` is day before yesterday matching the `campaignId` column. I want to show the difference of `cost` between yesterday's campaigns and day before yesterday's campaigns.

like

```
foreach($campaignReports as $campaignReport)
{
    $difference = $campaignReport->cost - $campaignReport->dayBeforeYesterdayCost; 
}
```

Can anyone help me in building this query using Query Builder or Eloquent?

Comment: What's wrong with writing two queries that get yesterday's cost and the day before yesterday's cost and subtracting?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. Yes, I can make another query inside foreach loop to query costDayBeforeYesterday. But I was thinking it in doing in single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a relation in your `CampaignReport` model that calculate difference between yesterday's cost and the day before that

```
public function dayBeforeYesterdayCost() {
     $dayBeforeYesterday = Carbon::parse($this->report_date)->subDays(1); //return date of day before yesterday

     $dayBeforeYesterdayCost = CampaignReport::where('campaignId', $this->campaignId)
     ->where('report_date', $dayBeforeYesterday)
     ->first();

     return $dayBeforeYesterdayCost ? $dayBeforeYesterdayCost->cost : 0;
}


public function lastDayDifference() {
     $difference = $this->cost - $this->dayBeforeYesterdayCost; 
     return $difference;
}
```

Now you can return `$campaignReports` with `lastDayDifference` relation like this:

```
 $campaignReports = CampaignReport::where(['report_date' => "$yesterday", 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id])
->with('lastDayDifference')
->orderBy('report_date', 'desc')
->paginate(25);
```

At the end you have one object attached to your every single `$campaignReport`

Comment: Thank you @Mohammad Hosseini. The problem is I don't have 'dayBeforeYesterdayCost' column in 'campaign_report' table. I want to get assign this value within the query.

Comment: @AmandeepSingh I have update my answer and add ```dayBeforeYesterdayCost``` in model. Check Please. If  ```$dayBeforeYesterday ``` return dates as timestamp and your dates in your ```report_date``` have different format you can use ```->format('Your format')``` at the end of the  ```$dayBeforeYesterday```

Answer (score 1):

Group by date(report_date) which will just give you the date part, order by the same descending, then just take the values for yesterday and the day before. Something like:

```
CampaignReport::select(DB::raw('date(report_date) report_date', DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
    ->where('report_date','>=',$twoDaysAgo) 
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id])
    ->groupBy('report_date')
    ->orderBy('report_date', 'desc');
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. The 'report_date' is already in the where clause. I can figure out how it will work.

Comment: Take it out of the query though, or use Carbon to just get the last two days grouped by date. I'll edit my answer to add an example.